# How to invert parentheses?

Tags: c#

I want to convert this `()` into this `) (`

Like for example `(1+2)` to `) 1+2(`

i have tried this

```
char[] cArray = text.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cArray[i] == '(')
            {
                cArray[i] = ')';

            }
            if (cArray[i] == ')')
            {
                cArray[i] = '(';
            }
        }
        string p=new string(cArray);
        return p;
```

but it does not work

Comment: Food for thought: What happens when first condition is true?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that after you've changed `(` to `)`, the second `if` statement will immediately be true, so the character is flipped back again. The reverse *isn't* true though - if you start off with `)` that will be flipped by the second statement, but then it won't be flipped back again. The net result is that all `)` characters will be flipped to `(`, but that's all. So an input of `"(((foo)))"` would return `"(((foo(((`.

The simplest way to fix that is to use an `else` statement:

```
char[] cArray = text.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    if (cArray[i] == '(')
    {
        cArray[i] = ')';
    }
    else if (cArray[i] == ')')
    {
        cArray[i] = '(';
    }
}
return new string(cArray);
```

Alternatively, you could use a `switch` statement, which would be simpler if you had a lot of different cases to consider:

```
char[] cArray = text.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    switch (cArray[i])
    {
        case '(':
            cArray[i] = ')';
            break;
        case ')':
            cArray[i] = '(';
            break;
        // No need for a default as it would be a no-op
    }
}
return new string(cArray);
```

A `switch` statement will only evaluate the expression once (on each iteration, of course) so you don't need to worry about the two cases interfering with each other.

Answer (score 5):

Use `else` before the second `if` as follows:

```
char[] cArray = text.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    if (cArray[i] == '(')
    {
        cArray[i] = ')';

    }
    else if (cArray[i] == ')')
    {
        cArray[i] = '(';
    }
}
string p = new string(cArray);
return p;
```

Comment: This is actually a hilarious Q/A pair to read, made up my day on SO :)